# C++ Skipping elements in a one d array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an assignment with several ways to manipulate an array, but I'm having trouble with one of the parts.

I am reading about 50 numbers into the array from a .txt file

And for every odd location in the array (1,3,5,…), I have to subtract it from the previous even location (0,2,4,…) and store results in the odd location.  Then I print out all values in the array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
void oddMinusEven(int ary[],int num)
{
    for(int idx = ary[0]; idx<num; ary[idx+2])
    {
        ary[idx] = ary[idx+2]-ary[idx];
        cout<<ary[idx]<<endl;
    }
}
```

How do I do this? If you could provide some examples, that would be great.

Comment: What specifically is your question? How to read the values from file into array?

Comment: Pretty sure that's supposed to be `int idx = 1;` in that initializer list. I'd start there. In fact, neither the increment (which doesn't) nor the initializer look right. You may need to review `for-loop` basics in your text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do:

```
void oddMinusEven(int ary[], int num) {
    for(int i = 1; i < num; i += 2) {
        ary[i] = ary[i-1] - ary[i];
        std::cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << ary[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```